# Drawing and filling in shapes

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, shapes

How do you draw AND fill in shapes? For example, drawRect draws a rectangle with whatever color you chose, but it leaves the middle with no color, and fillRect fills a rectangle with whatever color you chose, but it leaves the border with no color. How do you combine drawRect AND fillRect? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First fill the rectangle and then draw on top of it.**:

```
class MyCanvas extends JComponent {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) The correct method to override for custom painting a `JComponent` is `paintComponent(..)` 2) The `super` method should immediately be called in order to paint the BG and erase any previous drawing. 3) It is good practice for a custom component to return a sensible size from `getPreferredSize()` to assist the layout manager to know what size to award it. 4) Also good practice to use `@Override` notation where appropriate.

Comment: Correct, my intention was to show how to draw the rounded rectangle instead of full JComponent.